# Error while passing an argument to procedure in excel vba

Tags: vba, excel

```
Sub sumtotal_of_month()
Dim a As Integer
a = 0

For i = 2 To 365
    If (Sheets("Sheet1").Range("F" & i).Value = 1 And Sheets("Sheet1").Range("D" & i).Value <> "") Then
    a = a + Sheets("Sheet1").Range("D" & i).Value
End If
Next i
MsgBox (a)
End Sub
```

Code above works fine, but when I try to substitute **"1"** with parameter **month**, it doesn't provide any output. This code is very amateur, because I am just a beginner. I use Excel 2007.

```
Sub sumtotal_of_month(month As Integer)
Dim a As Integer
a = 0

For i = 2 To 365
    If (Sheets("Sheet1").Range("F" & i).Value = month And Sheets("Sheet1").Range("D" & i).Value <> "") Then
    a = a + Sheets("Sheet1").Range("D" & i).Value
End If
Next i
MsgBox (a)
End Sub
```

Comment: maybe you're not passing a valid `month` value: check the call statement and the value of the parameter it's being passed with

Comment: Use debugging to see what value month parameter has before passing it to the procedure. Make sure that the value passed has integer type.

Comment: Please show how you are calling the sub

Comment: @RyszardJędraszyk, as the elder said: "repetita juvant"

Comment: In fact, Month is a native VB function. Have no chance to see if it is reserved or not or can be override but just want to sound it.

Comment: @smozgur You can overwrite `month`, though it is clearly not a good practice.

Comment: Minor point: `MsgBox (a)` should just be `MsgBox  a`. When using a function as a sub, you don't put parentheses around the argument(s). With just 1 argument it is harmless. With multiple arguments it is a syntax error.

Comment: @JohnColeman Passing one argument to a sub within parentheses is not always harmless since it has a syntactical meaning; passing an argument within parentheses forces VBA to pass the argument by value even if the sub expects it to be by reference.

Comment: @JohnColeman, thanks for clarifying that. I don't have pc access so no chance to see how it works. weird but obviously my old friend VB allows that.

Comment: @M.Doerner Good point. I should have said "mostly harmless". In a `msgbox` it almost always is.

Answer (score 0):

given you have to check what value you are passing as `month` parameter to your sub, you can simplify your sub as follows:

```
Sub sumtotal_of_month(month As Integer)
    Dim a As Double

    With Worksheets("Sheet1")
        a = WorksheetFunction.SumIf(.Range("F2:F365"), month, .Range("D2:D365"))
    End With
    MsgBox a
End Sub
```

Comment: thanks u so much for the reply . your code runs fine, but MsgBox doesn't to pop up.

Comment: @AshwithUllal   It is impossible for this code to "run fine" without a message box popping up, Thus either the code isn't running at all or it is throwing an error, one which you might have suppressed by an ill-advised `On Error Resume Next`. If you want help, you need to show the calling code.